# Slow docker HTTP request chrome on windows host on Chrome only

Tags: docker, google-chrome

Setup:

docker 3.3.3 on Windows 10 host w/ WSL
container: CentOS8 container with httpd + php-fpm, mapped to host's 8080 port
test script: an empty PHP script

What I'm seing:
Processing the request takes nothing inside the container or in WSL:

```
[container] curl -w %{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total} localhost
0.000596:0.002195:0.002207
[WSL] curl -w %{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total} localhost:8080
0.000402:0.002630:0.002642
```

However, loading `localhost:8080` in Chrome on the host I get `Waiting (TTFB) 2.05s` which is crazy. There are no reported DNS or proxy times or anything connection-related, just TTFB. If running Chrome in incognito mode, this goes away, but not if just disabling all plugins in normal mode.

The same does not happen in Firefox, which loads the request instantly.

More context: this only occured recently, presumably after some update to either Win or Chrome.

I'm so puzzled by this and at the inherent productivity loss and have no idea where to take debugging further so I really hope someone has run into this problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out: On Chrome I had the Xdebug cookie set up for the domain; but there was no debugging IDE to listen for the Xdebug callback; the 2s were just the timeout of Xdebug connecting to nowhere.

Solution: clear Xdebug cookies.